# Using @PreAuthorize with openapi-tools

Tags: java, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using openapi-generator-maven-plugin for code generation

```
            <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
            <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.1</version>
```

And I need to have @PreAuthorize annotation on precise API method.

```
@RestController
@Validated
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class SomeController implements SomeApi {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER_ADMIN') || hasRole('ROLE_DIGITAL_REP') || hasRole('ROLE_FIELD_REP')")
    public ResponseEntity<SomeDto> getSomeInfo() {
        return ResponseEntity
            .status(HttpStatus.OK)
            .body("some info");
    }
```

It does not work because you can't use Spring annotations inside class (SomeApi calls overriden version of getSomeInfo inside). So my question is - is that possible to add @PreAuthorize for API endpoint during code generation step ? I've found discussion here https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/1975, but it is not clear was tis solved or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to do it by custom templates. Here is the nice video about it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jp2y15Xgk9g&t=1175s&ab_channel=Cloud-NativeDevelopment and my custom template looks like this:

```
        @RequestMapping(
        method = RequestMethod.{{httpMethod}},
        value = "{{{path}}}"{{#singleContentTypes}}{{#hasProduces}},
        produces = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-accepts}}}"{{/hasProduces}}{{#hasConsumes}},
        consumes = "{{{vendorExtensions.x-content-type}}}"{{/hasConsumes}}{{/singleContentTypes}}{{^singleContentTypes}}{{#hasProduces}},
        produces = { {{#produces}}"{{{mediaType}}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/produces}} }{{/hasProduces}}{{#hasConsumes}},
        consumes = { {{#consumes}}"{{{mediaType}}}"{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/consumes}} }{{/hasConsumes}}{{/singleContentTypes}}
        )
    {{#vendorExtensions.x-custom-role}}
        @PreAuthorize("{{{.}}}")
    {{/vendorExtensions.x-custom-role}}
```

and yml looks like this:

```
  /foo/bar/{tab}:
    get:
      operationId: someOperation
      x-custom-role: "hasRole('ROLE_USER_ADMIN')
```

Answer (score 2):

Really cool! thanks for sharing! It was very useful to start to investigate this topic! (Sadly I can't give you points as my account has not enough level.)

I share my solution as this could help someone else.

in the `api.mustache` file we added this code:

**Import PreAuthorize:**

```
{{#authMethods}}
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
{{/authMethods}}
```

**Add @PreAuthorize annotation to validate scopes:**

```
{{#authMethods}}
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('{{#scopes}}SCOPE_{{scope}}{{^-last}}, {{/-last}}{{/scopes}}')")
{{/authMethods}}
```

**Clarifications:**

Comment that we validate our endpoints by scopes defined in the openapi yaml, in the standard security section [more info](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/) and also comment that we use openApi generator version 6.1.0, maybe in the future they change the way how you can get the scopes.

Useful document that explains how to custom your template:
https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/templating